# Which of of these two SSDs perform better?

Tags: ssd

Hello I have been buying pc parts, am almost done

Thing is I am stuck in a dilemma with which SSDs to go with. My friend recommends I go with [Samsung 970 Evo plus 2TB](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-MZ-V7S2T0BW-970-EVO-Plus/dp/B07MLJD32L/ref=sr_1_3?crid=18ULV85NNRQPI&keywords=samsung+970+evo+plus+ssd+2tb+nvme+m.2&qid=1679568038&sprefix=samsung+evo+ssd+m.2+2t%2Caps%2C64&sr=8-3)  as he says is the best performance you can get for money. But its only available at max 2TB size. I found this one  [WD_BLACK SN850X 4TB M.2 2280 PCIe Gen4](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0B7CQ2CHH?psc=1&th=1&linkCode=gs2&tag=rpg0a-21) it has 4TB capacity, which is ideal

Performance is my top concern, so I am willing to forego space/capacity needs for it. Between the Samsung SSD and the WD Black SSD I linked to above, Does the WD black SSD perform worse?? or are they tied?

Or is my friend correct in his assertion that the Samsung SSD is the best available for performance?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The samsung listed is a PCIe gen 3 drive and is limited to about 3000mb/s.
The other one clearly states its a pcie gen 4 drive and runs at about 7000mb/s.

The rest depends on your motherboard if all your NVMe sockets are gen 3 then it won't matter at all as 3500mb/s(approx) will be your hard limit.

You may have to buy a PCIe gen 4 nvme add in card if your motherboard doesn't support gen 4.

If you have gen 4 this is the Samsung equivalent.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/SSD-Samsung-NVMe-PCIe-retail/dp/B08QJHLC8J/

Between the 980 and your other drive you would have to search out specific benchmarks.